# Rails 3 save model and redirect using coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, model, coffeescript

I have user class (using devise) and my User class has email subscriptions

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :email_sub, :class_name => "Subscriptions::EmailSub", :dependent => :destroy

end
```

I have a route

```
match 'profile', :controller => 'users', :action => 'view_profile'
```

and related controller that calls a specific file

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def profile
    @subscriptions_email_sub = current_user.email_sub
  end

end
```

And in the profile.html.erb file have a form (technically in a partial included in the template but I don't think that will make a difference) where the user can use radio buttons to set subscription options (subscribed or unsubscribed).  The button part of the form is below:

```
  <%= form_for(@subscriptions_email_sub) do |f| %>
    ...
    <tr>
      <td>Announcements</td>
      <td><%= f.radio_button :announcements, 'announcements', :checked => @subscriptions_email_sub.announcements %></td>
      <td><%= f.radio_button :announcements, 'announcements', :checked => !@subscriptions_email_sub.announcements %></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Updates about the website and service</td>
    </tr>
    <%= f.submit "Update Subscriptions", :id => 'update_subs' %>
  <% end %>
```

I'm trying to add coffeescript so when the user clicks the button it saves the model and notifies the user the settings have been updated (or an alert if there's an error).

(Alternatively I'm fine saving the model and reloading the whole page.)

So far I have in users.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $('#update_subs').click ->
    $('form').submit();
```

I can't figure out how to get the page to reload.  I think the form submit will cause it to use the controller for Subscriptions::EmailSub which will then try to load app/views/subscriptions/email_subs/show.html.erb  I suspect I may have to use javascript to save the class and the reload the page.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that code in `users.js.coffee`, you can make the form remote:

```
<%= form_for(@subscriptions_email_sub), :remote => true do |f| %>
```

This will submit the form asynchronously, expecting a JS response (unless you specify another content-type such as JSON).

You'll need to have a controller action to handle this update, presumably your `SubscriptionsController`.

It should respond to javascript requests:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js
  ...

  def update
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
    ...

    respond_with(@subscription)
  end
end
```

Then you can simply add an `update.js.coffee` file to your views/subscriptions folder and add any changes you want to make to the DOM in there, just as you would for regular javascript.

```
# update.js.coffee
alert "Email subscription updated!"
$('form').ignite_fireworks()
```